# Joomla! 1.5.23 on Mac not using relative links

Tags: php, macos, joomla

I'm on a Mac 10.8.4, running Joomla! 1.5.23 out of the Mac's default Apache 2 instance.
Everything's been fine for six months or so, but today when I tried to access my Joomla site at:

```
http://localhost/~george/mysite
```

I get 404 errors for all the linked files from index.php

Inside index.php I link to JS and CSS files e.g.:

```
<script src="templates/mytemplate/scripts/custom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="templates/mytemplate/css/style.css" />
```

and Chrome shows me that these links are resolving to:

```
http://localhost/templates/mytemplate/scripts/custom.js
```

as opposed to:

```
http://localhost/~george/mysite/templates/mytemplate/scripts/custom.js
```

the latter URL returns the document as per usual.

Any ides what's been changed in Apache, Joomla, or elsewhere that's causing this to happen, and how to revert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual cause in my case was an incorrect setting for `$live_site` in **configuration.php**, but your points are all valid.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, you should use the Joomla coding stansards to import css and js files, like so:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript( JUri::root() . "templates/mytemplate/scripts/custom.js" );
$doc->addStylesheet( JUri::root() . "templates/mytemplate/css/style.css" );
```

Just on a side note, I would recommend upgrading to Joomla 2.5+ as there are security issues with 1.5, however if you're unable to do tgis, please atleast upgrade the to the latest of the 1.5 series, which is 1.5.26

Hope this helps